# full width div not stretching to browser width in Bootstrap - non-responsive template

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've just started building a website using bootstrap - non responsive template, and observed that my full width div (one with blue background) not stretching to full browser width when viewed resizing the browser window. Even though I added `width: 100%;` its making no difference. Please see attached the screngrab.

Also if I removed the 'navbar-fixed-top' class from main navigation, then navigation background also starts behaving in the same manner. Can anyone let me know whats going wrong here.

**Note: The same thing happening in bootstrap template too if I add a full width div to any div block with container class.**

[image]

**Update**
here is the snippet of html code:

```
<div class="sub-header"> <!--div with blue background-->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          ------inner content -----
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and CSS code:

```
.sub-header { background: #0094e0; height: 80px; border-top: 1px solid #0082c5; border-bottom: 1px solid #0082c5; }
```

Comment: could you post or put in a fiddle the HTML markup please

Comment: I doubt bootstrap provide full browser with. Cause if u look into code you will know, bootstrap by default dont provide 100% width, but we can achive.  check the doc http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: You are using non responsive BS template, meanwhile you want the div reacting to the browser width. Can you explain more detail what is you trying to achieve from this question ?

Comment: @Nucleo 1985, I want to have a normal full width background (blue bg div) to backside of my content appearing inside container class div. hope it clarifies your query.

Comment: is the background on the body or on the html tag?

Comment: @Richlewis, thanks for your interest....but I've never yet created a Jsfiddle...and still don't know how :P However you could simply add a parent div with some background color to any div with container class in bootstrap - non-responsive template and see the result. Pardon me if asking much :)

Comment: @ravk why dont you create a class called blue with a background-color of #0094e0 and add that to the container? to be honest though your question doesnt really make sense, you seem to want responsive features but are using a non responsive template..Clarification here would be great

Comment: @Richlewis, I could surely add a class to give container div blue background. But objective here is to show a full width div (like a 'band') appearing backside of my content expanding to full browser width. That is the reason I'm looking outside container div and not inside of it. Respect your point, but I guess nothing odd in wanting a full width div even though your website has static appearance. If its confirmed that this issue has no solution, I'll see to add a class as you said. **BUT** what one should do when navbar bg also collapses in same manner on removing `navbar-fixed-top` class.

Comment: i would suggest 1) learn to create a jsfiddle or 2) push your code to as server and  provide a link to view your current progress.. To be able to answer effectively we need to see code to diagnose the problem.. at the moment it is unclear on what you want to achieve, thanks

Comment: @Richlewis, for #1 i would definitely love, for #2 site is just started to develop so couldn't put anything on server. I agree that one needs to see code to diagnose the issue, but in absence of mine code...you could see the same issue happening in default bootstrap - non responsive template too. Either remove 'navbar-fixed-top' or add a parent div as I want to any container class div and you could see the issue immediately. Though this might be lot I'm asking you guys, but what could be best to diagnose issue directly from a signed off template :)

Comment: I don't know what your doing but i have removed 'navbar-fixed-top' and all that happens is the navabr is no longer fixed. post your complete html markup in your question please...

Comment: Just remove the 'navbar-fixed-top' class and after that either 'restore down' your browser (to some low width so window gets horizontal scroll) or resize it then on scrolling to complete right you should see that div background of class `navbar navbar-default` is not touching the right side boundary of browser window and leaving lots gap even though default template text 'Link Link Link' appearing on its correct position. Meanwhile, I'm looking the way to post my code.